# No WIFI adapter found Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, dell

In wifi settings I get "No wifi adapter found. Make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged and turn on". Once I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS I had this problem first time but somehow was able to overcome it. Unfortunately after few months I tried to use bluetooth but it also did't work. Trying to fix it unfortunately get me back to no WIFI adapter found error. Tried many solutions without succes. Currently `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` show:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0050]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

my laptop is dell precision 7710. I can't find any hardware switch to turn dell-bluetooth or dell-wifi hard block to no. Previously for a moment had windows and wifi worked fine. Currently linux is my only system. Can someon help? What other logs should I post? Thank you.

Comment: thanks that worked. I knew there may be sth like this but didn't found working keys combination.

Answer (score 1):

To remove `Hard block` from `Wireless` and `Bluetooth`, try:

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>.

As per [Dell Precision 7710 Mobile Workstation Keyboard Guide](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000130100/dell-precision-7710-mobile-workstation-keyboard-guide), key combination of <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> would toggle wireless on/off.